# Triangle pattern in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a triangle in Java with a specific number pattern. I am having problems coming up with a mathematical equation that outputs these numbers/pattern once the user enters the number of lines:
[image: SEE IMAGE]

My code works fine but the numbers are not correct. Does anyone know an equation for that pattern?

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of lines: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        for(int i =0;i<rows;i++) {
            int number = 1;
            System.out.format("%"+(rows-i)*2+"s","");
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
                System.out.format("%4d",number);
                number = number * (i - j) / (j + 1);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a "mathematical equation", you just need **2 `for` loops**, one counting down and another counting back up. --- But, if you insist on a single loop and a mathematical equation, try looping `j` from `-i` to `i` (inclusive), and print value `Math.abs(j) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas)'s comment, 2 for loops would work well:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of lines: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        for(int i =0;i<rows;i++) {
            System.out.format("%"+4*(rows-i+1)+"s","");
            for(int j=i+1; j>1; j--)
                System.out.format("%4d", j);
            for(int j=1; j<=i+1; j++)
                System.out.format("%4d", j);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```